# Android | Kotlin : App Reading from InputStream to Buffer Problems

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth, soundpool

I am starting to experience some latency issues between the time I receive data and when the app plays a sound. Previously I only loaded up 5 sounds using SoundPool and had close to 0 latency, but now after creating an extra 42 variables for loading different sounds to as well as increasing my input buffer, I am experiencing these latency issues. I am not sure if it is due to how long it takes to evaluate the buffer elements, or because of all the extra varaibles I included to store SoundPool sounds. Is there any way I could make my code more efficient in terms of using all these variables?

Edit (2/17/21) : Found that while having the buffer elements output to logcat, that sometimes the data being received is off by one element sometimes and sometimes not. There has to be something wrong with how im reading the info from the input buffer but I cannot for the life of me figure it out

Edit (2/19/21) : Seems to only be a problem if the array > size 6
Also finding that when the input stream recieves an input, it reads it 2-4 times extra, all with different values as well

Here's my code snippet where the functionality takes place :

```
private class ConnectedThread(private val mmSocket: BluetoothSocket?, c: Context) : Thread() {
        private val mmBuffer: ByteArray = ByteArray(12) // mmBuffer store for the stream
        private var a1 = 0
        private var b1 = 0
        private var c1 = 0
        private var d1 = 0
        private var e1 = 0
        private var f1 = 0
        private var g1 = 0

        private var a2 = 0
        private var b2 = 0
        private var c2 = 0
        private var d2 = 0
        private var e2 = 0
        private var f2 = 0
        private var g2 = 0

        private var a3 = 0
        private var b3 = 0
        private var c3 = 0
        private var d3 = 0
        private var e3 = 0
        private var f3 = 0
        private var g3 = 0

        private var a4 = 0
        private var b4 = 0
        private var c4 = 0
        private var d4 = 0
        private var e4 = 0
        private var f4 = 0
        private var g4 = 0

        private var a5 = 0
        private var b5 = 0
        private var c5 = 0
        private var d5 = 0
        private var e5 = 0
        private var f5 = 0
        private var g5 = 0

        private var a6 = 0
        private var b6 = 0
        private var c6 = 0
        private var d6 = 0
        private var e6 = 0
        private var f6 = 0
        private var g6 = 0

        private var soundPool: SoundPool? = null
        private var soundStream1: Int? = 0
        private var soundStream2: Int? = 0
        private var soundStream3: Int? = 0
        private var soundStream4: Int? = 0
        private var soundStream5: Int? = 0
        private var temp: ByteArray = ByteArray(12)
        var read: Int = 0
        var context: Context

        init {
            this.context = c
        }

        override fun run() {
            var numBytes: Int = 0// bytes returned from read()
            soundPool = SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0)
            a1 = soundPool!!.load(context, R.raw.c4, 1)
            b1 = soundPool!!.load(context, R.raw.d4, 1)
            c1 = soundPool!!.load(context, R.raw.e4, 1)
            d1 = soundPool!!.load(context, R.raw.f4, 1)
            e1 = soundPool!!.load(context, R.raw.g4, 1)
            f1 = soundPool!!.load(context, R.raw.c4, 1)
            g1 = soundPool!!.load(context, R.raw.d4, 1)

            a2 = soundPool!!.load(context, R.raw.c4, 1)
            b2 = soundPool!!.load(context, R.raw.d4, 1)
            c2 = soundPool!!.load(context, R.raw.e4, 1)
            d2 = soundPool!!.load(context, R.raw.f4, 1)
            e2 = soundPool!!.load(context, R.raw.g4, 1)
            f2 = soundPool!!.load(context, R.raw.c4, 1)
            g2 = soundPool!!.load(context, R.raw.d4, 1)

            a3 = soundPool!!.load(context, R.raw.a3, 1)
            b3 = soundPool!!.load(context, R.raw.b3, 1)
            c3 = soundPool!!.load(context, R.raw.c3, 1)
            d3 = soundPool!!.load(context, R.raw.d3, 1)
            e3 = soundPool!!.load(context, R.raw.e3, 1)
            f3 = soundPool!!.load(context, R.raw.f3, 1)
            g3 = soundPool!!.load(context, R.raw.g3, 1)

            a4 = soundPool!!.load(context, R.raw.a4, 1)
            b4 = soundPool!!.load(context, R.raw.b4, 1)
            c4 = soundPool!!.load(context, R.raw.c4, 1)
            d4 = soundPool!!.load(context, R.raw.d4, 1)
            e4 = soundPool!!.load(context, R.raw.e4, 1)
            f4 = soundPool!!.load(context, R.raw.f4, 1)
            g4 = soundPool!!.load(context, R.raw.g4, 1)

            a5 = soundPool!!.load(context, R.raw.a5, 1)
           b5 = soundPool!!.load(context, R.raw.b4, 1)
            c5 = soundPool!!.load(context, R.raw.c5, 1)
            d5 = soundPool!!.load(context, R.raw.d5, 1)
            e5 = soundPool!!.load(context, R.raw.e5, 1)
            f5 = soundPool!!.load(context, R.raw.f5, 1)
            g5 = soundPool!!.load(context, R.raw.g5, 1)

            a6 = soundPool!!.load(context, R.raw.c4, 1)
            b6 = soundPool!!.load(context, R.raw.d4, 1)
            c6 = soundPool!!.load(context, R.raw.c6, 1)
            d6 = soundPool!!.load(context, R.raw.f4, 1)
            e6 = soundPool!!.load(context, R.raw.g4, 1)
            f6 = soundPool!!.load(context, R.raw.c4, 1)
            g6 = soundPool!!.load(context, R.raw.d4, 1)


            // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs.
            while (true) {
                // Read from the InputStream.
                try {
                    numBytes =
                        mmSocket!!.inputStream.read(mmBuffer, numBytes, mmBuffer.size - numBytes)
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Input stream was disconnected", e)
                    break
                }

                playNote(mmBuffer)


            }
        }

        fun playNote(buf: ByteArray) {
            var count: Int = 0

            if (read == 0) {
                read++
            } else {
                for (i in buf) {
                    Log.i("data", count.toString() + " " + i.toString())
                    if (i != '0'.toByte()) {
                        when (count) {
                            2 -> {
                                if(buf[count] != temp[count] && buf[count+1] != temp[count+1]){
                                    soundPool?.stop(soundStream1!!)
                                }
                                soundStream1 = noteCheck(buf[count], buf[count + 1])
                            }
                            4 -> {
                                if(buf[count] != temp[count] && buf[count+1] != temp[count+1]){
                                    soundPool?.stop(soundStream2!!)
                                }
                                soundStream2 = noteCheck(buf[count],buf[count+1])
                            }
                            6 -> {
                                if(buf[count] != temp[count] && buf[count+1] != temp[count+1]){
                                    soundPool?.stop(soundStream3!!)
                                }
                                soundStream3 = noteCheck(buf[count],buf[count+1])
                            }
                            8 -> {
                                if(buf[count] != temp[count] && buf[count+1] != temp[count+1]){
                                    soundPool?.stop(soundStream4!!)
                                }
                                soundStream4 = noteCheck(buf[count],buf[count+1])
                            }
                            10 -> {
                                if(buf[count] != temp[count] && buf[count+1] != temp[count+1]){
                                    soundPool?.stop(soundStream5!!)
                                }
                                soundStream5 = noteCheck(buf[count],buf[count+1])
                            }
                        }
                        temp[count] = i
                    } else if (i == '0'.toByte()) {

                        temp[count] = i
                    }
                    count++
                }
                read = 0

            }


        }
        fun noteCheck(check1 : Byte, check2 : Byte): Int? {
            var sndStream: Int? = 0
            if (check1 == 'a'.toByte()) {

                when (check2) {
                    '1'.toByte() -> sndStream= soundPool?.play(a1, 1F, 1F, 0, 0, 1F)
                    '2'.toByte() -> sndStream= soundPool?.play(a2, 1F, 1F, 0, 0, 1F)
                    '3'.toByte() -> sndStream= soundPool?.play(a3, 1F, 1F, 0, 0, 1F)
                    '4'.toByte() -> sndStream= soundPool?.play(a4, 1F, 1F, 0, 0, 1F)
                    '5'.toByte() -> sndStream= soundPool?.play(a5, 1F, 1F, 0, 0, 1F)
                    '6'.toByte() -> sndStream= soundPool?.play(a6, 1F, 1F, 0, 0, 1F)
                }
            } else if (check1 == 'b'.toByte()) {

                when (check2) {
                    '1'.toByte() -> sndStream= soundPool?.play(b1, 1F, 1F, 0, 0, 1F)
                    '2'.toByte() -> sndStream= soundPool?.play(b2, 1F, 1F, 0, 0, 1F)
                    '3'.toByte() -> sndStream= soundPool?.play(b3, 1F, 1F, 0, 0, 1F)
                    '4'.toByte() -> sndStream= soundPool?.play(b4, 1F, 1F, 0, 0, 1F)
                    '5'.toByte() -> sndStream= soundPool?.play(b5, 1F, 1F, 0, 0, 1F)
                    '6'.toByte() -> sndStream= soundPool?.play(b6, 1F, 1F, 0, 0, 1F)
                }
            } else if (check1 == 'c'.toByte()) {

                when (check2) {
                    '1'.toByte() -> sndStream= soundPool?.play(c1, 1F, 1F, 0, 0, 1F)
                    '2'.toByte() -> sndStream= soundPool?.play(c2, 1F, 1F, 0, 0, 1F)
                    '3'.toByte() -> sndStream= soundPool?.play(c3, 1F, 1F, 0, 0, 1F)
                    '4'.toByte() -> sndStream= soundPool?.play(c4, 1F, 1F, 0, 0, 1F)
                    '5'.toByte() -> sndStream= soundPool?.play(c5, 1F, 1F, 0, 0, 1F)
                    '6'.toByte() -> sndStream= soundPool?.play(c6, 1F, 1F, 0, 0, 1F)
                }
            } else if (check1 == 'd'.toByte()) {

                when (check2) {
                    '1'.toByte() -> sndStream= soundPool?.play(d1, 1F, 1F, 0, 0, 1F)
                    '2'.toByte() -> sndStream= soundPool?.play(d2, 1F, 1F, 0, 0, 1F)
                    '3'.toByte() -> sndStream= soundPool?.play(d3, 1F, 1F, 0, 0, 1F)
                    '4'.toByte() -> sndStream= soundPool?.play(d4, 1F, 1F, 0, 0, 1F)
                    '5'.toByte() -> sndStream= soundPool?.play(d5, 1F, 1F, 0, 0, 1F)
                    '6'.toByte() -> sndStream= soundPool?.play(d6, 1F, 1F, 0, 0, 1F)
                }
            } else if (check1 == 'e'.toByte()) {

                when (check2) {
                    '1'.toByte() -> sndStream= soundPool?.play(e1, 1F, 1F, 0, 0, 1F)
                    '2'.toByte() -> sndStream= soundPool?.play(e2, 1F, 1F, 0, 0, 1F)
                    '3'.toByte() -> sndStream= soundPool?.play(e3, 1F, 1F, 0, 0, 1F)
                    '4'.toByte() -> sndStream= soundPool?.play(e4, 1F, 1F, 0, 0, 1F)
                    '5'.toByte() -> sndStream= soundPool?.play(e5, 1F, 1F, 0, 0, 1F)
                    '6'.toByte() -> sndStream= soundPool?.play(e6, 1F, 1F, 0, 0, 1F)
                }
            } else if (check1 == 'f'.toByte()) {

                when (check2) {
                    '1'.toByte() -> sndStream= soundPool?.play(f1, 1F, 1F, 0, 0, 1F)
                    '2'.toByte() -> sndStream= soundPool?.play(f2, 1F, 1F, 0, 0, 1F)
                    '3'.toByte() -> sndStream= soundPool?.play(f3, 1F, 1F, 0, 0, 1F)
                    '4'.toByte() -> sndStream= soundPool?.play(f4, 1F, 1F, 0, 0, 1F)
                    '5'.toByte() -> sndStream= soundPool?.play(f5, 1F, 1F, 0, 0, 1F)
                    '6'.toByte() -> sndStream= soundPool?.play(f6, 1F, 1F, 0, 0, 1F)
                }
            } else if (check1 == 'g'.toByte()) {

                when (check2) {
                    '1'.toByte() -> sndStream=
                        soundPool?.play(g1, 1F, 1F, 0, 0, 1F)
                    '2'.toByte() -> sndStream=
                        soundPool?.play(g2, 1F, 1F, 0, 0, 1F)
                    '3'.toByte() -> sndStream=
                        soundPool?.play(g3, 1F, 1F, 0, 0, 1F)
                    '4'.toByte() -> sndStream=
                        soundPool?.play(g4, 1F, 1F, 0, 0, 1F)
                    '5'.toByte() -> sndStream=
                        soundPool?.play(g5, 1F, 1F, 0, 0, 1F)
                    '6'.toByte() -> sndStream=
                        soundPool?.play(g6, 1F, 1F, 0, 0, 1F)
                }
            }

        return sndStream
        }


    }
```

Logcat output: I am sending the same exact data everytime but its different sometimes

```
2021-02-19 04:08:24.408 16533-21821/com.example.airboard I/data: ---------------------------------------------
2021-02-19 04:08:24.408 16533-21821/com.example.airboard I/data: 0 48
2021-02-19 04:08:24.408 16533-21821/com.example.airboard I/data: 1 97
2021-02-19 04:08:24.408 16533-21821/com.example.airboard I/data: 2 51
2021-02-19 04:08:24.408 16533-21821/com.example.airboard I/data: 3 98
2021-02-19 04:08:24.408 16533-21821/com.example.airboard I/data: 4 51
2021-02-19 04:08:24.408 16533-21821/com.example.airboard I/data: 5 48
2021-02-19 04:08:24.408 16533-21821/com.example.airboard I/data: 6 48
2021-02-19 04:08:24.408 16533-21821/com.example.airboard I/data: 7 100
2021-02-19 04:08:24.408 16533-21821/com.example.airboard I/data: 8 51
2021-02-19 04:08:24.408 16533-21821/com.example.airboard I/data: 9 101
2021-02-19 04:08:24.408 16533-21821/com.example.airboard I/data: 10 51
2021-02-19 04:08:24.408 16533-21821/com.example.airboard I/data: 11 48
2021-02-19 04:08:24.594 16533-21821/com.example.airboard I/data: ---------------------------------------------
2021-02-19 04:08:24.594 16533-21821/com.example.airboard I/data: 0 48
2021-02-19 04:08:24.594 16533-21821/com.example.airboard I/data: 1 48
2021-02-19 04:08:24.594 16533-21821/com.example.airboard I/data: 2 51
2021-02-19 04:08:24.595 16533-21821/com.example.airboard I/data: 3 98
2021-02-19 04:08:24.595 16533-21821/com.example.airboard I/data: 4 51
2021-02-19 04:08:24.595 16533-21821/com.example.airboard I/data: 5 48
2021-02-19 04:08:24.595 16533-21821/com.example.airboard I/data: 6 48
2021-02-19 04:08:24.595 16533-21821/com.example.airboard I/data: 7 100
2021-02-19 04:08:24.595 16533-21821/com.example.airboard I/data: 8 51
2021-02-19 04:08:24.595 16533-21821/com.example.airboard I/data: 9 101
2021-02-19 04:08:24.595 16533-21821/com.example.airboard I/data: 10 48
2021-02-19 04:08:24.595 16533-21821/com.example.airboard I/data: 11 48
2021-02-19 04:08:24.627 16533-21821/com.example.airboard I/data: ---------------------------------------------
2021-02-19 04:08:24.627 16533-21821/com.example.airboard I/data: 0 48
2021-02-19 04:08:24.627 16533-21821/com.example.airboard I/data: 1 97
2021-02-19 04:08:24.627 16533-21821/com.example.airboard I/data: 2 51
2021-02-19 04:08:24.627 16533-21821/com.example.airboard I/data: 3 98
2021-02-19 04:08:24.627 16533-21821/com.example.airboard I/data: 4 51
2021-02-19 04:08:24.627 16533-21821/com.example.airboard I/data: 5 48
2021-02-19 04:08:24.627 16533-21821/com.example.airboard I/data: 6 48
2021-02-19 04:08:24.627 16533-21821/com.example.airboard I/data: 7 100
2021-02-19 04:08:24.627 16533-21821/com.example.airboard I/data: 8 51
2021-02-19 04:08:24.627 16533-21821/com.example.airboard I/data: 9 51
2021-02-19 04:08:24.627 16533-21821/com.example.airboard I/data: 10 48
2021-02-19 04:08:24.627 16533-21821/com.example.airboard I/data: 11 48
2021-02-19 04:08:24.814 16533-21821/com.example.airboard I/data: ---------------------------------------------
2021-02-19 04:08:24.814 16533-21821/com.example.airboard I/data: 0 48
2021-02-19 04:08:24.814 16533-21821/com.example.airboard I/data: 1 97
2021-02-19 04:08:24.814 16533-21821/com.example.airboard I/data: 2 51
2021-02-19 04:08:24.814 16533-21821/com.example.airboard I/data: 3 98
2021-02-19 04:08:24.814 16533-21821/com.example.airboard I/data: 4 51
2021-02-19 04:08:24.814 16533-21821/com.example.airboard I/data: 5 48
2021-02-19 04:08:24.814 16533-21821/com.example.airboard I/data: 6 48
2021-02-19 04:08:24.814 16533-21821/com.example.airboard I/data: 7 100
2021-02-19 04:08:24.814 16533-21821/com.example.airboard I/data: 8 51
2021-02-19 04:08:24.815 16533-21821/com.example.airboard I/data: 9 101
2021-02-19 04:08:24.815 16533-21821/com.example.airboard I/data: 10 51
2021-02-19 04:08:24.815 16533-21821/com.example.airboard I/data: 11 48
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently my solution for this was figuring out reading the data into a ByteArray and then evaluating it was just not working properly. changed my read line to:

```
                           val ch =  mmSocket!!.inputStream.read().toChar()
                            mmBuffer[c23] = ch
                            c23++
```

and changed my buffer from a ByteArray to a CharArray and got better results.